# Avoid java package 'freemarker' to execute commands

Tags: java, freemarker

I am using Apache Freemarker as my template engine.

I have a security issue with it that I am not sure how to handle:
admin users are able to modify the templates, but in case they will set an input like:

```
`<#assign ex = "freemarker.template.utility.Execute"?new()>${ ex("pwd")}`.
```

Then the code will call:

`freemarker.core.Environment.process()`

And the command "pwd" will be executed.

How can I avoid it?

Comment: From version 2.3.19 onwards there's `TemplateClassResolver.SAFER_RESOLVER` that you could use to inhibit Execute entirely, would that be a solution?

Comment: That would be great. Do you have an example how to use it?

Comment: Got it! Thanks! This is how it should be used:
    Environment env = .....;
    env.setNewBuiltinClassResolver(TemplateClassResolver.SAFER_RESOLVER);

Comment: don't hesitate to write up the solution and your code example (maybe not just that line but the complete initialisation) as an answer, **and accept it** so that future visitors can benefit of it. That's the SO way of doing things.

Answer (score 1):

In my use case, I was retrieving Freemarker templates and merging the template with Java code like this:

```java
    String templateName = "Whatever from any variable"
    StringTemplateLoader stringLoader = new StringTemplateLoader();
    stringLoader.putTemplate(templateName, templateContent);
    Configuration cfg = new Configuration(Configuration.VERSION_2_3_31);
    cfg.setTemplateLoader(stringLoader);
    // Create Template class object & get the Template
    Template template = cfg.getTemplate(templateName);
    // Render the template into a Writer, here a StringWriter
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    // Merge the model & template
    template.process(dataModel, writer);
```

and this was subject to the same attack as the OP.

My solution was to set the `SAFER_RESOLVER` as said in the comments but by setting the value in the template instance itself like this:

```java
    template.setSetting("new_builtin_class_resolver", "safer");
```

After adding that line in my code (just after the template instanciation) my code was safe.

It is very important to know that even you implement this, you will be safer if you also keep the `api_builtin_enabled` to `false` (default value)
like explained in the [doc](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_expert.html#ref_buitin_api_and_has_api).

[This article](https://ackcent.com/in-depth-freemarker-template-injection/) shows that even with the more strict resolver `ALLOWS_NOTHING_RESOLVER` if the `api_builtin_enabled` is set to true, you can still have the vulnerability.